# How to work around selenium library hanging on specific windows version

Tags: python, selenium, go

I have a bit of a complicated problem. First off: github.com/tebeka/selenium is the library I am using for chromedriver/selenium. Here is my basic code to start the chromedriver (works):

```
const (
    chromeDriverPath= `chromedriver.exe`
    port= 8080
)
service, err := selenium.NewChromeDriverService(chromeDriverPath, port)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer service.Stop()

// Connect to the WebDriver instance running locally.
caps := selenium.Capabilities{"browserName": "chrome"}
wd, err := selenium.NewRemote(caps, fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/wd/hub", port))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

defer wd.Quit()
```

The problem lies when I run this on a windows server, running Windows Server 2012. This is the part of my code that fails.

```
for {
    _, err := wd.FindElement(selenium.ByXPATH, xpath1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Waiting to get to get to webpage")
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Successfully found page.")
        fmt.Println("Getting verification token.")
        vT, err := wd.FindElement(selenium.ByXPATH, verificationTokenXpath)
        if err != nil{
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        VerifictionToken, err = vT.GetAttribute("value")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        break
    }
}
```

This is a simple block of code to continuously loop until the webdriver is at a specific webpage, in which case it will grab a token. The looping part will work fine, but once it finds the webpage, it will hang, before doing anything else. For example, in the code above: "Successfully found page." will never be printed. To clarify, this will only happen on this specific windows server.
If anyone knows the issue, please let me know.

EDIT:
The problem has boiled down to this: wd.FindElement is blocking when the element is found. This only happens on specific operating systems such as Windows Server 2012. Does anyone have an suggestions on how to fix? I do need to get the value of a web element, maybe I could parse the html?

Comment: This feels like 2 different questions.  Do you want to know how to gracefully handle `wd.FindElement` blocking? Or do you want to know how to communicate with an external process (such as a python script)?

Comment: @JoshuaKolden Upon reexamining the problem, I see that wd.FindElement is blocking when the element is found, but returns an error normally. Again, this only happens on specific OS versions. For example, windows 10 works, while windows server 2012 does not. I edited the post above as well.